# Unable to boot after kernel upgrade

Tags: boot, multi-boot, kali-linux, grub2, ubuntu-15.10

My PC triple boot Windows 10, Ubuntu 15.10 and Kali 2016.1.
It boots from Ubuntu Grub. Everything worked fine until yesterday. Yesterday Kali released version 4.4 of the kernel and I installed it. Then I moved to Ubuntu and run `update-grub` to teach Grub that something changed. Then I retry to boot Kali did not boot anymore.

If I selected advanced options and run Kali with previous 4.3 kernel everything works as expected, but if I try to boot updated kernel the system freezes on purple screen and the light of the ssd keeps blinking on, so I'm forced to shutdown the system.

Is there anyone that knows a possible solution to this annoying issue?

**UPDATE:** Kali devs seem have released a kernel patch. Now I can boot the system, but cannot start the desktop.

The following link contains my dmesg output

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwa4KznQadAtRGE3T1BjMXJKRTQ/view?usp=sharing